# calculate the totall number of uniqe words of the first column of a list

Tags: python, nlp

I have a file that consists of many Persian sentences. each line contains a sentence, then a "tab", then a word, again a "tab" and then an English word. I have to know just the number of unique words of the sentences (the words after tabs should not be in calculation). For that I changed the file to a list, so I have a list that contains a lot of lines and each line contains three indices; the sentence, a Persian word, an English word. Now I can achieve the sentences. The problem is that, the code I wrote returns the number of unique words of each line separately. For example if the file has 100 lines it returns 100 numbers, each in a new line. But I want the summation of all the numbers and have just one number which shows the total number of unique words. How can I change the code?

```
from hazm import*

def WordsProbs (file):
    with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        normalizer = Normalizer()
        for line in f1:
        tmp = line.strip().split("\t")
        tmp[0] = normalizer.normalize(tmp[0])
        corpus.append(tmp)
   for row in corpus:
       UniqueWords = len(set(row[0].split()))
       print (UniqueWords)
```

The sample data:

باد  بارش برف وزش باد، کولاک یخبندان سطح  wind

Comment: Are you applying the `Normalizer` only on the sentence?

Comment: yes. because I extracted them from a very larger corpus. But I tagged the words after tabs myself. so just the sentences need normalizing

Comment: So another question, does this module has a `word_tokenizer` function by any chance? Like NLTK

Comment: yes. hazm is something like NLTK in Persian.

Comment: Yep I see, it's actually a simple translation of NLTK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming tmp[0] contains the sentence from each line, the individual words in the sentence can be counted without building a corpus.

```
from hazm import*

def WordsProbs (file):
    words = set()
    with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        normalizer = Normalizer()
        for line in f1:
            tmp = line.strip().split("\t")
            words.update(set(normalizer.normalize(tmp[0].split())))
    print(len(words), "unique words")
```

I can't test it because on my machine, the English word "wind" shows up in the first column after cutting and pasting your sample data.

Comment: I know that it's essential to split tmp[0], but when I run the code, the error below occurs. How can I fix it?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'
>>>

Comment: Here's a small file. you can test on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution. As you said you have list of lines. So the following code should get you what you want

```
sample_data = """This is One sentence   word1   word2
This is Second sentence word1   word2"""
lines = sample_data.split("\n")
word_list = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.split("\t")[0]
    word_list.extend(line.split(" "))
print len(set(word_list))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. This error occurs

Comment: List does not have split object but if your data is as you described line should of string type.

Comment: `len(set(word_list))` will only return the number of sets contain unique words in each line, and it's not what OP intends.

Comment: Nopes. For the above input it would print 5. Is it not the expected output.
`word_list` will contains all words (space separated) from file (except the ones which are separated by tabs) and set will remove duplicated from them

Comment: I have a file that because I wanted to achieve just the sentences, I put them in a list by "corpus = []". Now I have to write the rest of the code on this list not the file.

Comment: @saurabhbaid Yes, I see it's seems that you're right. :-) and you got my plus.

Comment: But note that extending the lists like this for a large file is not an optimized and pythonic way, you should consider using more proper approaches like list comprehensions ot generator expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You an use `collections.Counter` in order to count the number of words after splitting:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def WordsProbs (file_name):
    with open (file_name, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        all_words = chain.from_iterable(word_tokenizer(line.split(None, 1)[0]) for line in f1)
        return Counter(all_words)
```

The `chain.from_iterable` will chain the splitted words together as an integrated iterator, so that the `Counter` can create a counter object from all of the words.

If you just want the number of all unique words `len(WordsProbs(file_name))` will give you that, but another way is using a set on the iterator that we created with `cahin.from_iterable`:

```
def WordsProbs (file_name):
    with open (file_name, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        all_words = chain.from_iterable(word_tokenizer(line.split(None, 1)[0]) for line in f1)
        return len(set(all_words))
```

And if you want the number of unique words for each line:

```
def WordsProbs (file_name):
    with open (file_name, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        each_line_numbers = [len(set(word_tokenizer(line.split(None, 1)[0]))) for line in f1)
        return each_line_numbers
```

Comment: Thanks but this error occurs: NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Comment: @suneye There was a simple typo, try it now.

Comment: Well it returns:   Counter({'باد': 1, 'غرقش': 1, 'کاش': 1, 'مناطق': 1, 'حیف': 1, 'کار': 1, 'افزایش': 1, 'پایان': 1, 'تهران': 1, 'مجبورم': 1,  'الان': 1, 'رطوبتهای': 1,

Comment: But I need  JUST the summation of the numbers. I mean just one number

Comment: @suneye So what's the problem with that? you have only one of those words in your text.

Comment: I'm trying it on a another small file. The main file is very large

Comment: @suneye I saw this *I have to know just the number of unique words of the sentences*, but it's OK, let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code in the middle returns one number. But I see in the file that unique words are more than this number.